# Ember model result empty in template but filled in inspector

Tags: javascript, ember.js

This is my first app in ember.
I have an API url that output this JSON:

```
{"search":{"id":"123","idate":"2016-11-20","fdate":"2016-11-25","keywords":["cuccioli","gattini","rocco"]}}
```

**App structure:**

*app/adapters/application.js*

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'v1',
    host: 'http://myhost'
});
```

*app/models/search.js*

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    idate: DS.attr('date'),
    fdate: DS.attr('date'),
    keywords: DS.attr()
});
```

*app/routes/search.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        // this not work
        return this.get('store').findRecord('search', 123);

        // this work
        /*return this.get('store').createRecord('search', {
                "id": "456",
                "idate": "2016-11-24",
                "fdate": "2016-12-01",
                "keywords": ["ssss", "mmmm"]
            }

        );*/
    }
});
```

*app/templates/components/search.hbs*

```
<h2>Search page</h2>

<ul>
    {{#each model as |s|}}
    <li>id {{s.id}}</li>
    <li>idate {{s.idate}}</li>
    <li>fdate {{s.fdate}}</li>
    <li>keywords {{s.keywords}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

*app/router.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('search');
});

export default Router;
```

The problem is that the **model seems to be empty in template**, but it is **filled in inspector**.

[screenshot of template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgpRx.png)

Thank you in advance for your support. I'll appreciate every answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The findRecord method will always return a promise that will be resolved with the record. so instead of `each` helper you can simply say `model.id`.
- While including `search` component don't forget to include `model` property.
  `{{search model=model }}`